# Is their a way to slide a div down in css

Tags: css, html, hover, slide

I'm trying to get it so when you hover your mouse over a `<div>` it will slide down 5px and I would prefer it to be made in css.  (if possible)

the `<div>` I'm trying to moves name is "tothetop".

Thanks for all help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**CSS3 transition** will do the job pretty well!

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyujoy/1/edit)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  width:160px;
  height:80px;
  background:#f46;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s; // you can use also 400ms if you want
          transition: 0.4s;
}
.box:hover{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

---

**IF you want to fallback to jQuery:**

<kbd>**[jQuery LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyujoy/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( evt ){
  var pos = evt.type=='mouseenter' ? 10 : 5 ;
  $(this).stop().animate({marginTop : pos}, 500); 
});
```

<sup>(Make always sure to animate a CSS property you have already defined in the CSS for your element (in this example is `margin`))</sup>

http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/stop/
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

use jquery and call slidedown on the object.

example shown here: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

or if you are just trying to move stuff instead of showing / hiding, use jquery animate

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="tothetop">
    this move down 5px
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tothetop {position:relative}
#tothetop:hover {top:5px}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  div:hover {
  margin-top:15;
  }
</style>
```

this simple code would slide the div down 15 pixels, you get the idea